# If $\Delta u(x,y)=0,\ \ \text{in}\ B,\ \ \ u(x,y)=\sin(x)\ \ \text{on}\ \partial B$ then compute $u(0,0)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm having trouble solving the following PDE problem. We're in the open unit ball in the plane, centered at the origin,

$$B=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2},\ \ x^2+y^2<1\}$$

The following boundary problem is given

$$\Delta u(x,y)=0,\ \ \text{in}\ B,\ \ \ u(x,y)=\sin(x)\ \ \text{on}\ \partial B$$

> The problem is the following: Use the mean value theorem to find the value $u(0,0)$.

I'm not so sure how to deal with this one. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It isn't the mean value theorem for PDEs. It is the [Mean Value Theorem for harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property). And this is a direct application of it, so there are no twists or deep concepts that need to be worried about.

Comment: I know there's a formula for it, but I'm a bit confused what the answer will be. According to my book, I get the following

$$u(0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial B}u(\sigma) d \sigma$$

here I believe $\sigma$ is a point on the boundary. My guess is that for a point on the boundary, $u$ becomes $sin(x)$, from the given information. But I'm not so sure about how I would evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, $u(x) = \sin x$ on the boundary, of $B,$
By the mean value property together with the change of variables $y =-z$ that is $d\sigma(z)= d\sigma(y)$
$$u(0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial B}u(z) d \sigma(z) =\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial B}\sin(z) d \sigma(z) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial B}\sin(y) d \sigma(y) = -u(0)$$

That is $$u(0) =0$$

Comment: Thanks for the response! Why did you make the change of variable $y = -z$? And when it comes to evaluating the integral are you doing it in polar coordinates?

Comment: I make the change of variable because the function $\sin x$ is odd and the spherical surface measure is invariant by rotation

Comment: So by doing the change of variables you end up showing that $u(0)=-u(0)$ and thus you can conclude that $u$ must be 0?

Comment: @James that is really the point

Comment: @GuyFsone I see that you have created a new tag named (mean-value-theorem). I wanted to let you know that I made a post on meta about the new tag: [Should we have a tag for mean value property of harmonic functions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27410)

Comment: @GuyFsone Cool, thanks for the response!